Issue with aligning part numbers and titles in ToC using tocloft
I am currently working on a document using tocloft package, trying to ensure that the \part titles in my ToC are aligned consistently at a fixed position (24pt).
However, the titles of the parts in the ToC are not aligned properly. The indentation of the titles seems to depend on the length of the Roman numeral used for the part number (e.g., "I", "II", "III"), which causes the titles to be offset differently.
I also noticed that my part titles weren't perfectly aligned with the chapter titles (whether in Part I or Part II).
EDIT: I am using \documentclass{report}. My engine is XeLaTeX. Semi-bold font is not defined. I don't know why, but when I chose \bfseries, semi-bold font is automatically used (and not bold font as expected).
Here is a minimal example you can test. As you may notice, the issue persist even without any font customization.
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\begin{document}    
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\part{Titre de la partie 1}
\chapter{Titre du chapitre 1}
\chapter{Titre du chapitre 2}

\part{Titre de la partie 1}
\chapter{Titre du chapitre 1}
\chapter{Titre du chapitre 2}
\end{document}


I've already tried adjusting the indentation and number widths using \cftpartnumwidth, but the issue persists. \cftpartnumwidth doesn't seem to respond, whereas cftchapnumwidth, on the contrary, works quite well. Maybe this is related to the fact that my part titles use Roman numerals?
To sum up, I would like:

the part numbers (Roman numerals) to be aligned at a fixed position, without causing indentation shifts in the titles.
the part titles to be consistently aligned whith chapter titles, regardless of the length of the Roman numeral.

Thank you very much in advance for your time and assistance!
Best,
Sam

Please provide a full but minimal example others can copy and test as is. It is important for us to know which class and packages you are using. You provide no such information.

Welcome to TeX.SE. Do please state the engine (LuaTeX?), the document class, and the pqckages that need to be employed. What's the main document font sizre? How or where is \semiboldfont defined?

Just a guess: The standard classes do not use \numberline for the part entries to the ToC but something like \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}. So there is a static distance after the number instead of a width for the number (and space). There are other classes like the KOMA-Script classes, that use \numberline also for the part entries and allow to configure the width of number (and space).

I've included a minimal example, as well as the class and packages I am using. I am using XeLaTeX engine. I didn't define semiboldfont, but when I set \bfseries, the font is automatically formatted semi-bold (and not bold as expected). This is not a problem, since I specifically want semi-bold font for this document.

@slalomeuse Regarding xelatex, this might be interesting for you: https://www.texdev.net/2024/11/05/engine-news-from-the-latex-project

Please add the sniplet to the MWE such that there only one piece of code to copy, as your MWE does not give the provided image.

There is something wrong with toclofts handling of the part number it seems. (xelatex not needed). The output does not react to, say, \setlength\cftparnumwidth{2cm}

@daleif AFAIK, this is because of not using \numberline as I've explained above.

The standard classes handle part entries to the ToC different than other entries. Concrete do they not use \numberline for the number. So tocloft is not able to change the width used for the number.
You can use another class like memoir or scrreprt to allow such changes. Both classes also provide their own interface to configure the ToC without loading tocloft. The memoir interface AFAIK is very similar to tocloft. Here an example using scrreprt:
\documentclass[12pt,sfdefaults=false,chapterprefix,numbers=noenddot]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[entryformat=\bfseries\large,linefill=\TOCLineLeaderFill,numwidth=25pt]{tocline}{part}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[entryformat=\bfseries\normalsize,linefill=\TOCLineLeaderFill,numwidth=25pt]{tocline}{chapter}

\begin{document}    
\tableofcontents
\part{Titre de la partie 1}
\chapter{Titre du chapitre 1}
\chapter{Titre du chapitre 2}


\part{Titre de la partie 1}
\chapter{Titre du chapitre 1}
\chapter{Titre du chapitre 2}
\end{document}


See the KOMA-Script documentation for the used commands and the differences to the standard classes.
BTW: \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} should not be needed for several years, therefore I've removed it. And a4paper is default with KOMA-Script classes, so I've also removed it.
To make the same work with report you would need to load not only package tocbasic instead of tocloft, but also patch \@part to replace the distance after the part number by usage of \numberline in the ToC entry:
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{tocbasic}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@part}{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}%
}{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\numberline{\thepart}#1}%
}{\typeout{\string\@part\space patch successfull}}{\PaTchFailue}
\makeatother

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[entryformat=\bfseries\large,linefill=\TOCLineLeaderFill,numwidth=25pt]{tocline}{part}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[entryformat=\bfseries\normalsize,linefill=\TOCLineLeaderFill,numwidth=25pt]{tocline}{chapter}

\begin{document}    
\tableofcontents
\part{Titre de la partie 1}
\chapter{Titre du chapitre 1}
\chapter{Titre du chapitre 2}


\part{Titre de la partie 1}
\chapter{Titre du chapitre 1}
\chapter{Titre du chapitre 2}
\end{document}



Thank you for your answer.
Your code works well as such, but when I try and include your modification in my own document, for some reason the issue seems to persist.
I don't know what I did wrong.
The same goes for @daleif suggestion with memoir class. I tried it, but I've got the same problem in the end.

Ok, I have a hint. This is probably due to dis command: \titleformat{\part}[display]{\normalfont\huge}{\normalfont\fontsize{18}{18}\selectfont\partname~\thepart}{6pt}{\bfseries\fontsize{30}{30}\selectfont}\titlespacing*{\part}{0pt}{-17.5pt}{0pt}
When I delete it, your solution seems to work. The problem is that I want to keep my part title style.

@slalomeuse If you'd use the scrreprt example, you could simply reconfigure the \part style using \RedeclareSectionCommand instead of using titlesec. See the KOMA-Script documentation for more information.

@slalomeuse BTW: Using the same value for the font size and the baselineskip is mostly not a good idea.

As @cacohah mentions in the comments tocloft cannot change \part data in the toc as it does not provide an interface it can latch on to.
But the memoir (disclaimer: is maintainer) class does and it has its own slightly modified version of tocloft included. The openany make it resemble report
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany]{memoir}

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % no need anumore
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
% \usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\setlrmarginsandblock{1in}*1
\setulmarginsandblock{1in}*1
\checkandfixthelayout

% \usepackage{tocloft} % already in memoir slightly modified

% no equivalent
%\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{-13pt}
%\setlength{\cftaftertoctitleskip}{36pt}
%\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\fontsize{30}{30}\selectfont\bfseries}

\settocdepth{subsubsection}
\setsecnumdepth{subsubsection}

%\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
%\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\bfseries\fontsize{16}{16}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterfont}{\bfseries\fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsectionfont}{\normalfont\fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont}
\setlength{\cftbeforepartskip}{24pt}
\setlength{\cftbeforechapterskip}{12pt}

\cftsetindents{part}{0pt}{24pt}
\cftsetindents{chapter}{0pt}{24pt}
\cftsetindents{section}{24pt}{24pt}

\renewcommand{\cftpartdotsep}{\cftnodots}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterdotsep}{\cftnodots}
\renewcommand{\cftsectiondotsep}{2}

\setlength\cftpartnumwidth{1cm}
\setlength\cftchapterindent{0pt}
\setlength\cftchapternumwidth{\cftpartnumwidth}
\setlength\cftsectionindent{\cftpartnumwidth}

\begin{document}    
\newpage
\tableofcontents*

 \newpage
\part{Titre de la partie 1}
  \chapter{Titre du chapitre 1}
  \section{Section 1}
  \section{Section 2}
\chapter{Titre du chapitre 2}

\part{Titre de la partie 1}
\chapter{Titre du chapitre 1}
\chapter{Titre du chapitre 2}
\end{document}



Thank you for your answer. Your solution, as well as @cabohah solutions, only work if I remove this command:
\titleformat{\part}[display]{\normalfont\huge}{\normalfont\fontsize{18}{18}\selectfont\partname~\thepart}{6pt}{\bfseries\fontsize{30}{30}\selectfont}\titlespacing*{\part}{0pt}{-17.5pt}{0pt}
However, I would like to keep the format of my titles. How can I do this?

@slalomeuse titlesec is incompatible with both memoir and the KOMA classes. They have their own infterfaces to change the sectional output that you should use instead. Basically it overwrites how the class expects \part to behave.

In a future version of memoir, I'll add a warning if titlesec is used.
